# Multiple Criteria to pull multiple values in Excel Summary Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**Note:** I can easily accomplish this, using Pivot tables but need to figure out using excel formulas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Problem Description:**

I need to read number, and output to  summary table based on multiple criterion.

Tab 1: Raw data with information.

Tab 2: Example of dummy data.

Basically, need to read text from column C, D, E in Tab 1 based on 2 criterion, Pillar & Group, in column A & B, in Tab 1) and then spit results in Tab 2.

Note, that in some cases there are more than one Date/value to spit out.

Criteria should be based on Column A and B (Group and Pillar), and when the criteria meets, it may or may not have more than 1 value.

For example: Group 1, Pillar 1 might have 2 dates/values in column C, D, E so I have to pull both dates in my summary table.

[image: Raw Data]
[image: Desired Output]

Find data in `example.xlsx` below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n41c553oQGM9V0LCMzUciDfuE-fphNs8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1413212/edit) to provide sample data as part of it, otherwise it will be useless to others once the link is dead. It would also be a good idea to include what you have tried so far and how it failed to meet expected results

Comment: How can I add data? There was no file attachments button therefore I shared my personal file link in the body message. Plz advise

Comment: As text in the body of your question. See [this](https://superuser.com/editing-help) for help on formatting if you need it. If a screen cap is better, you can upload it on http://www.imgur.com and link to it

Comment: You're going to want to correct the multiple misspellings of 'pillar' in column `B`, too, or else no solution is going to work TOO well ;)

Comment: I don’t understand.   Please improve your description of what you want to do, and post data that illustrates your goal more clearly.

Comment: Hi Alex - I did fix the Pillar misspellings. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Hi Scott - What do you not understand? can you elaborate. Thanks for your willingness to help.

Comment: What I need and I think what @Scott is asking for, is a clear sample of the desired results. As it is now, the output is little more than a description. In fact, the dates in the output are not to be found in the Tab1 Raw data. Create a clear set of input that can be visually mapped to the doctored desired output sample. Then, describe how Input is mapped to Output. Be sure to have examples that cover the complex scenarios as well. Limit the sample to what is needed to understand the mapping. Use a [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for the input so we can cut/paste

Comment: @TedD. said it fairly well.  I would add, why does cell ``D2`` in the second sheet say “any other text” instead of “8/1/2019, 9/10/2019”?  What’s supposed to go in ``B3:D6``?  Also, what’s the significance of the color coding on the input sheet?  Also, your terminology is weird.  You say “Tab 1: Raw data with information Tab 2: Example of dummy data.”  Data with information?  That’s redundant, like ice on the rocks, or orange à l’orange.  And why do you say that tab 2 is dummy data? Is tab 1 ***real*** in some sense?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I presume that you mean that tab 1 is dummy input data and tab 2 is the expected output for that input.  But, since that’s not what you said, it’s unclear.  Also, do you have a way for generating Column `A` on sheet 2, or is that part of the question?  Also, how do you feel about VBA solutions?  Also, as a matter of presentation, “group” and “pillar” isn’t intuitive.  I guess it means something for you, but, for the sake of writing an understandable question, why not make it “group” and “subgroup”, or “state” and “county”, or “game” and “inning”, or something relatable?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming that your source data in TAB 1 is in `A2:E16`.
- Fill Criteria i.e **Group Nu** in `A2` of `TAB   2`.
- Enter this Array (CSE) Formula in `B2 of TAB 2`, finish with  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, fill Right then Down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$E$16, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$2, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$16), ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$E$16)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$E$16))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- No need to use 2 Criteria since the problem can be solved using only 1 Criteria i.e. `Group Number`.
- Keep changing the `Group Number in A2` to get another combinations.

**Note:**

- In case you want to use both criteria i.e. `Group Number & Pillar`, then you need to use this Array Formula in `C2` of `TAB 2`.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$E$16, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$2, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$16)*COUNTIF($B$2, Sheet1!$B$2:$B$16), ROW(Sheet1!($C$2:$F$16)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$C$2:$F$16))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```

[image]

- Fill `Group Nu. & Pillar` in `A2 & B2` of `TAB 2` before you enter Formula.
- Keep changing the `Group Number and Pillar` in `A2 & B2` to get another combinations.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: ThanksRajesh. I will try it and let you know. Regards,

Comment: Write your concern why this post has been Down voted, help me to put my view behind it and to improve also !!